# kpm restore ubuntu: The requested feature is not implemented

Tags: asp.net, mono, asp.net-core

I try to run the asp.net Home samples on my Ubuntu 14.04
But on every kpm restore i get the following:

```
wuetrs@wuetrs-N750JK:~/repos/Home/samples/HelloMvc$ kvm list

Active Version              Runtime Location             Alias
------ -------              ------- --------             -----
  *    1.0.0-beta2          Mono    ~/.kre/packages      default

wuetrs@wuetrs-N750JK:~/repos/Home/samples/HelloMvc$ kpm restore
Restoring packages for /home/wuetrs/repos/Home/samples/HelloMvc/project.json
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Kestrel'
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Kestrel/1.0.0-beta2
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/1.0.0-beta2.
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/1.0.0-beta2
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-beta2.
  CACHE https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener'
  GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener/1.0.0-beta2.
----------
System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.PackageUtilities+<OpenNuspecStreamFromNupkgAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.IO.Stream].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Restore.NuGet.PackageFeed+<OpenNuspecStreamAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.IO.Stream].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RemoteWalkProvider+<GetDependencies>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.LibraryDependency]].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations+<FindLibraryEntry>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.GraphItem].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations+<CreateGraphNode>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.GraphNode].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreOperations+<CreateGraphNode>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.GraphNode[]].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand+<RestoreForProject>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Boolean].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.RestoreCommand+<ExecuteCommand>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
----------
Restore failed
The requested feature is not implemented.
```

as kvm list show, i have KRE-Mono.1.0.0-beta2 installed
so i tried to change the package.json to get the 1.0.0-beta2 packages, but probably it have nothing to do with that :(

my mono version is:

```
wuetrs@wuetrs-N750JK:~$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
TLS:           __thread
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  amd64
Disabled:      none
Misc:          softdebug 
LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
GC:            sgen
```

any idea please ?

Comment: What version of mono do you have ?

Comment: What's the best way to find the version ?

Comment: wuetrs@wuetrs-N750JK:~$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  amd64
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            sgen

Comment: the recommended mono version is greater than 3.6.1 so I think you should update your mono. I think you installed mono by using apt-get which is installing an older version. Try to compile and install mono from sources

Comment: ok, got it. i try that tomorrow and tell you after. tk you

Comment: yep, that was the point. tks @SuhasJoshi

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the solution, suggested b @SuhasJoshi was correct:

```
sudo apt-get remove mono-complete (or whatever package was installed)
```

then go with that:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: For future users: I've had the same issue with dnvm (the *latest* version of kpm) and this answer fixed it, too.

Comment: For what it's worth, I did this and completely borked my mono setup.  Your mileable may vary.